# Modifying flood fill algorithm for specific task

Tags: c#, wpf, flood-fill

I am trying to make a tile based game where tiles are filled with random colors and if the user clicks on a tile it disappears. This I have already accomplished.

[image]

Now, what I want to do is the tile disappears only if 2 or more adjacent tiles have the same color. I have used the flood fill algorithm to destroy tiles. How do I modify this code so that it works only if some count value is greater than 2.

This is the code that destroys a tile :

```
 private void Destroy(int x,int y,int old_Value,int new_Value)
    {
        if (GameArr[x,y].BlockValue == old_Value)
        {
            //if some count > 2 then only
            GameArr[x, y].BlockValue = 0;

            Destroy(x + 1, y, old_Value, new_Value);
            Destroy(x - 1, y, old_Value, new_Value);
            Destroy(x, y + 1, old_Value, new_Value);
            Destroy(x, y - 1, old_Value, new_Value);

        }
    }
```

How do I get this count value?

- If I pass a count variable in the method itself and check if value
  exceeds 2 and then destroy, it won't destroy the first two tiles.
- If I make another method to check if tiles are destroyable, it would set the blockValues to 0 while counting.

How do I go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found my answer.

The count value was to be checked before I call my Destroy method

```
if (GameArr[i - 1, j].BlockValue == old_Value) count++;
       if (GameArr[i, j - 1].BlockValue == old_Value) count++;
       if (GameArr[i + 1, j].BlockValue == old_Value) count++;
       if (GameArr[i, j + 1].BlockValue == old_Value) count++;

       if(count>2)
            Destroy(i, j,GameArr[i,j].BlockValue,0);
```